# Dynamic Fields and Table Cache in Apache Ignite In-Memory Database

Tags: spring-boot, caching, ignite, database-caching

I am implementing the Apache Ignite In-Memory Database in sync with external Database (Primary DB) for spring boot application. In that How can I create a cache for dynamic entities from table that is present in the Primary DB for SQL queries that needs to be run on Ignite.
Eg. I have two tables one is table1 and other is table1_summ in this table1_summ is created from table1 so Is their any way we can fetch the Sql Fields from Primary table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In my primary DB my table is dynamically created so we can not specify the KeyFields or classSource for Caching the Data from table. and In our system we are continuous changing the query on that same table. I want If their any solution using apache Ignite we can create cahe for dyanamic table columns and get the data from cache using query

Comment: Just create proper `CacheConfiguration` in runime and the create cache via `ignite.getOrCreateCache(config)`